# Cordova CLI, Admob and Google Maps plugins conflict

Tags: cordova, google-maps, admob

i have trouble with admob and google maps plugins. When the ads appear, my maps blank. i think they both conflict. But i dont know how to solve it? Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothings is conflicting as I believe you are using google-phonegap-maps plugin and admob-pro.
Google-phonegap-map plugins needs to be tweaked when your working with any other framework. As it is running on Native View. If you put Background color to any DOM element It may reflect on your Map. Admob banner I guess applies some background (I couldn't exactly fetch out in what manner), But It does. So the work around I have came up with is to Overlap your banner and it will be solved.

```
admob.createBanner({
           /*parameter stuff, set one more parameter*/
            overlap : true,
})
```

and it will be done.
I guess you have already acknowledged on facebook.

Comment: First time? please eleaborate

Comment: Install the app,open the app, it works, close the app, open the app, fails, so on

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](https://github.com/roberthovhannisyan/cordova-plugin-google-play-services/issues/1). This issue is raised by the author of cordova-plugin-admob himself

Comment: The plugin [cordova-admob](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova) worked for me