# Google Play services plugin is not being installed with admobpro

Tags: cordova, google-play-services, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

When I am adding admob pro plugin to cordova it is not automatically fetching google play services. I tried to install google play servives manually before installing admob pro, then on running the build it is showing error that it cannot locate symbol files.

Comment: Suggest to have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709120/cordova-cli-admob-and-google-maps-plugins-conflict

Comment: @Gandhi I am not using any other plugin along with addmob. Problem is I can't figure out why google play services are not being installed automatically as show in the demo videos of plugin.

Comment: could you post your error trace?

Comment: i guess this link should help you out - https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/Difference-of-Plugin-IDs

Comment: @Gandhi thanks for the help bro. Finally got the plugin work.

Comment: Glad it worked. Could you let me know what exactly fixed your problem so that I can post the same in answer.thanks

Comment: @Gandhi I had to update the google play service library. After which I got the "Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/..." error, solution to which was given in link that you provided (in FAQ section).

Comment: Have posted the answer for others benefit. You can accept the same. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Cordova AdMobPro plugin, then as mentioned in the plugin documentation you gotta install some extras which include `Android Support Library, Android Support Repository and Google Play Services` too using `Android SDK Manager` to avoid build errors.

Also to avoid build errors with following error message "`Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/...`", you gotta avoid duplication of `google-play-services.jar` as mentioned in official FAQs.

Please check out this [link](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/Difference-of-Plugin-IDs) for more info. Hope it helps.